# Bootstrap margin and padding are not honoured

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome

I have a question on margin and padding with bootstrap. I set margin left  0.25 rem (ml-1 equivalent to 4 pixels) and the picture below shows my captured picture from inspector window - it is clearly missing left margin (margin is of the colour that is shown at the bottom). Similarly padding left and right are not honoured. Why?

[image]

Comment: You can also use the inspector to see the calculated margin and click on it to see where it is coming from, or in other words: You can see who overrules your settings.